# Books on Statistics and Optimization

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, book-recommendation

I'm trying to close gaps in my education especially in **Statistics** and **Optimization theory**. I had an awful class on Statistics so I want to learn it by myself. As for Optimization we had a pretty good class on Calculus of variations but I never used it, time passed and I forgot a lot of stuff. Also there are few topics in Probability Theory that I still "can't feel" very well, they are: *conditional expectation*, *multivariate distributions* and *sums/products of random variables*.

What books or courses can you recommend for me? I'm interested from perspective of both rigorous pure math and applications.

Comment: Why -1? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: I didn't down-voted your question but I fear that book recommendations even if I would allow them personally are not recommended on the M.SE... Fear of creating a marketplace instead of a problem and answer forum. Wait and see

Comment: @Moo, concerning Statistics -- OK. What about optimization and chosen topics in probability theory?

Comment: Type optimization books in the top right search window.

Comment: @Moo, if you can't answer don't answer at all. Don't worry, I'm able to use Google, but I'm interested not only in books but in people's opinions too.

Answer (score 1):

To start with optimization you should first consider linear programming:

- **Linear Programming** by Vasek Chvatal mostly an algebraical introduction to the topic
- **Linear Programming and Network Flows** by Mokhtar S.Bazaraa and John
  Jarvis which is a bit harder but introduce geometrical interpretation.

Comment: These books seems like a "math for porgrammers". Too easy for me, nevertheless thanks a lot!